# Some Powershell aliases in my profile are not loading, why?

Tags: powershell

Here's a section of my profile:

```
#alias gs='git status'
function GitStatus { & git status $args }
Set-Alias -Option AllScope -Name gs -Value GitStatus

# aliases - other ----------------------------------
function Touch { & echo $null >> $args }
Set-Alias -Option AllScope -Name touch -Value Touch
function LL { & ls }
Set-Alias -Option AllScope -Name ll -Value LL
function Open { & Invoke-Item $args }
Set-Alias -Option AllScope -Name open -Value Open

echo "Loading profile v6..."
```

My profile is at:

C:\Users\[USER NAME]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

The profile loads without any errors:

```
$ .$PROFILE
Loading profile v6...
```

But the `open` alias isn't loaded.

```
$ open .\coverage\report.html
open : The term 'open' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

But the `gs` alias is.

```
$ gs
On branch f/listener
Changes to be committed:
```

So how did I get in a situation where some of my alias load and some don't? There are no errors when the profile loads....

```
$ $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  1198
```

Comment: `(gal open).ReferencedCommand`

Comment: what is that? ..

Comment: If this command completes without error, then `open` alias is loaded, and this command show command referenced by alias. BTW, are you aware that PowerShell is not case sensitive?

Comment: Why are you making an alias for `open` == `Open`? Powershell function calls and variables are case insensitive. My guess would be that making an unnecessary alias is causing problems

Comment: I want something that matches bash. `open file.html` will work in bash but I'm on Windows for the moment

Comment: On Windows the command would be `start` (alias for `Start-Process`).

Comment: ok but I want it to be the same command as bash, which is why I want `open`

Comment: I tried `Set-Alias open Start-Process`. Works fine for me.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that worked, make it an answer and I'll mark it. I got the alias pattern above from TheScriptingGuy I believe. Don't know why it fails but the simpler version works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
Set-Alias open Start-Process
```

I tested and it works for me.

Comment: Ah so it was the case sensitivity that was killing my alias; it's weird that powershell uses case sensitive arguments to various commands while it is not case sensitive overall

Comment: The alias shouldn't be case-sensitive. The alias works for me regardless of how I enter the command.

Comment: In my original code I was depending on case sensitivity.